# NPM package with exports won't load in typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, es6-modules, commonjs

Our library needs to work both for projects using ESM modules and CommonJS. Therefore we built it with 3 different configurations: ESM, node16, and types.

This setup works for JavaScript projects with node. Both for CommonJS and for ESM (when putting `"type": "module"` in package.json).

However, when trying to use the library in a Typescript project, I get the following error

```
Cannot find module '@ltonetwork/lto' or its corresponding type declarations.
```

What's wrong about this setup?

---

#### TypeScript config

###### ESM

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "lib/esm",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "bundler"
  }
}
```

###### CommonJS

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "lib/cjs",
    "module": "node16",
    "moduleResolution": "node16"
  }
}
```

###### Types (`.d.ts` files)

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "lib/types",
    "declaration": true,
    "module": "node16",
    "moduleResolution": "node16",
    "emitDeclarationOnly": true
  }
}
```

#### package.json

In package.json, I use `exports` to specify which file to load

```
  "exports": {
    ".": {
      "types": "./lib/types/index.d.ts",
      "require": "./lib/cjs/index.js",
      "import": "./lib/esm/index.js",
      "default": "./lib/esm/index.js"
    },
    "./accounts": {
      "types": "./lib/types/accounts/index.d.ts",
      "require": "./lib/cjs/accounts/index.js",
      "import": "./lib/esm/accounts/index.js",
      "default": "./lib/esm/accounts/index.js"
    },
    "./types": "./lib/types/index.d.ts",
    "./constants": "./lib/constants.js",
    "./package.json": "./package.json"
  },
```

Comment: Not clear what you mean by "not working in a typescript project". Would be nice to see more of the package.json file, specifically the  `name` and `type` fields, i.e. what are you calling your package and is it an ESM-first, or CJS-first project? Need some more info to help out more. You got a link to the library?

Comment: @morganney When using the library in typescript, I get the "Cannot find module" error. I don't get any error when using the library in javascript using either import or require.
You can find the complete package.json here: https://github.com/ltonetwork/lto-api.js/blob/master/package.json